# Facebook share cache

Tags: facebook

Good morning all!

I'm developing the Facebook Share button feature on a site, but i'm having the following problem:

Imagine that i have an article that i want to share with the id=1

when i shared it, by doing:
`<a name="fb_share" type="icon_link" share_url="http://www.something.com/en/news.xhtml?id=1"/>`

all went good.

Now, i tried to share a different article (id=2)

this took me to the article with id=1.

Is there any cache problem on the facebook side, or he caches the page http://www.something.com/en/news.xhtml and discards the request parameters?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

use the  following service https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug , pass the url and facebook will flush the current cache.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was mentioned on the following developer thread on FB.

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=130747

Facebook share does cache pages with the same URL, but in the example you provided the URL is different, you could also try passing trough the date in the URL to make sure the page is unique. It may have been that you tried sharing that page before but the content then may have been different then ...

Mart